# File "Test.py", line 14 while True: ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax что делать с ней?

Tags: python

```
from colorama import init
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style
import pyowm

owm = pyowm.OWM('...', language ='ru')

init()
print( Back.MAGENTA )

while True:
    what = input('Что хотите сделать? (+, -, *, /, ^2, Погода, Выйти): ')

    if what == '^2':
        a =float(input('Введите число: '))
        elif what == 'Выйти': break            
        elif what == 'Погода':
            alert = print('...')
            place = input('...: ')
            observation = owm.weather_at_place(place)
            w = observation.get_weather()

    elif what == '+':
        a =float(input('Введите первое число: '))
        b =float(input('Введите второе число: '))
    elif what == '-':
        a =float(input('Введите первое число: '))
        b =float(input('Введите второе число: '))
    elif what == '*':
        a =float(input('Введите первое число: '))
        b =float(input('Введите второе число: '))
    elif what == '/':
        a =float(input('Введите первое число: '))
        b =float(input('Введите второе число: '))
    elif what == '^2':
        a =float(input('Введите первое число: '))
        b =float(input('Введите второе число: '))
    else:
        print( Back.RED )
        print('Неверный запрос')

        print ( Back.GREEN )

        if what == '+':
            c = a + b
            print('Результат: ' + str(c))
        elif what == '-':
            c = a - b
            print('Результат: ' + str(c))
        elif what == '*':
            c = a * b
            print('Результат: ' + str(c))
        elif what == '/':
            c = a / b
            print('Результат: ' + str(c))
        elif what == '^2':
            c = a * a
            print('Результат: ' + str(c))
        elif what == 'Погода':
            temp = w.get_temperature('celsius')['temp']
            print('В ' + place + ' сейчас ' + w.get_detailed_status())
            print('Температура: ' + str(temp) + ' градусов цельсия')
input()
```

```
File "Test.py", line 14
    while True:
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

что делать с этим?

Answer (score 1):

вместо

```
if what == '^2':
    a =float(input('Введите число: '))
    elif what == 'Выйти': break            
    elif what == 'Погода':
        ...
```

сделать

```
if what == '^2':
    a =float(input('Введите число: '))
elif what == 'Выйти': break            
elif what == 'Погода':
    ...
```